.Net 8 web API and Angular application getting error 405 after deployed into the IIS server
I have web application buit in .net 8 and angular. Both web api and angular are part of same solution. Everything working fine with visual studio but when I deployed application on IIS I get error 405.
I tried following things.

Enabling request filtering
Enabling tracing
Removing the handlers webDev etc
Removed Filters and middleware's
Enabling the CORS for all the origins

Everything works fine on the local development but when I am deploying into the IIS server its returning 405 method not allowed error.
But tried lot on the IIS like enable Request filtering etc, but I cant resolve it.
Below is my program.cs and I suspect JWT Authentication
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

#region Configure JWT authentication

// Load configuration from appsettings.json

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

// Configure JWT authentication

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audience").Value,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:SecretKey").Value))
    };

    // Optionally, configure other JwtBearer options
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "l", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter the Bearer token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            }
        },
        Array.Empty<string>()
    }
    });
});

#endregion

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/json" });
});

#region Add services to the container

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PublicPortalDBcontext");
var SecurityKey = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:SecretKey");
var Issuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer");
var audience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audience");

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
//Services Initialization

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connection));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();


#endregion

#region CORS 

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", cbuilder =>
    {
        cbuilder.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration.GetSection("corsURL:devUrl").Value
                            , builder.Configuration.GetSection("corsURL:testUrl").Value
                            , builder.Configuration.GetSection("corsURL:prodUrl").Value)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

#endregion

#region LOGGER

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);


#endregion LOGGER

#region Configure the HTTP request pipeline

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Portal V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";  // Optional: Set the Swagger UI route prefix
    });
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

//exception handling and logging middleware

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseCors("EnableCORS");

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();

#endregion

Request Header
accept:
application/json, text/plain, /
accept-encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language:
en-US,en;q=0.9,ta;q=0.8
connection:
keep-alive
content-length:
75
content-type:
application/json; charset=UTF-8
host:
localhost:85
origin:
http://localhost:85
referer:
http://localhost:85/
sec-ch-ua:
"Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
sec-ch-ua-mobile:
?0
sec-ch-ua-platform:
"Windows"
sec-fetch-dest:
empty
sec-fetch-mode:
cors
sec-fetch-site:
same-origin
user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
withcredentials:
true

Response Header
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Allow: GET, HEAD
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2024 08:11:50 GMT

Please assist me to resolve this issues. Thanks in Advance.

It seems you have enabled the fail request tracing , what's the logs for this 405 error? Which module return the 504?

Thanks for the quick reply @BrandoZhang, Please find my complete logs here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sE5uINnelvYCl4JUAIwN1oShKRlGEpMi?usp=sharing

what is the method/verb of the frontend's request?  (it's same-site according to what you posted so no OPTIONS request needs to be sent)
